# How to write all these three functions in Parent Component instead of writing in the child component - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am basically a beginner in React. I have a dashboard page where I display a React Table. I have a customize button which will open a popup page, this popup page has some check boxes allows me to show/hide those React columns. Initially all the check boxes in this popup page is set to true. When I uncheck a column that particular column get disabled.

[image]

Now I have written some functions (3 major functions) in the child component. For the simplicity of the application, I want to now move those 3 functions to the parent component.

This is my Child Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ActionCreators } from '../../../actions';
import './CustomizedView.scss';
// import Filter from '../../common/filter/filter';
import ButtonComponent from '../../common/button/ButtonComponent';


class CustomizedViewInv extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCheckChildElement = this.handleCheckChildElement.bind(this);
    // this.applyFilter = this.applyFilter.bind(this);
    this.resetFilter = this.resetFilter.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      items: this.props.items,
    };
  }

  getCheckBox(item) {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          value={item.id}
          // className='chkProd'
          type='checkbox'
          checked={item.isChecked}
          //disabled={d.poId !== null || d.status !== 'Responded'}
          onClick={(e) => { this.handleCheckChildElement(e); }}
        />
        {item.value}
      </div>);
  }

  handleCheckChildElement(event) {
    const { items } = this.state;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i = i + 1) {
      if(items[i].id === +event.target.value) {
        items[i].isChecked = !items[i].isChecked;
        break;
      }
    }
    this.setState({ items });
  }

  resetFilter() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i = i + 1) {
      items[i].isChecked = true;
    }
    this.setState({ items });
    console.log('Reset filter : > Items : ' + JSON.stringify(items));
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className='dashboardFilter-container' >
        <div className='bottomBar'>
          <ButtonComponent
            text='Apply'
            className='activeButton filterMargin-div'
            width='100'
            display='inline-block'
            // onClick={() => { this.props.applyFilter(); }}
          />
          <ButtonComponent
            text='Reset'
            className='greyedButton clear-dashboard-filter'
            width='100'
            display='block'
            marginTop='60'
            onClick={() => { this.resetFilter(); }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className='data-points-text'>
            <span> Columns </span>
          </div>
          <div className="App">
            {items.map((item) => {
                return this.getCheckBox(item);
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CustomizedViewInv.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({})).isRequired,
};

CustomizedViewInv.defaultProps = {
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomizedViewInv);
```

In my parent component, I have imported the child component. You can see a proptypes called items in Child Component.

Bascilly in the state of parent component, I have an object called filterItems

```
filterItems: [
        { id: 1, value: 'Col 1', isChecked: true },
        { id: 2, value: 'Col 2', isChecked: true },
        { id: 3, value: 'Col 3', isChecked: true },
        { id: 4, value: 'Col 4', isChecked: true },
        { id: 5, value: 'Col 5', isChecked: true },
        { id: 6, value: 'Col 6', isChecked: true },
        { id: 7, value: 'Col 7', isChecked: true },
        { id: 8, value: 'Col 8', isChecked: true },
        { id: 9, value: 'Col 9', isChecked: true },
        { id: 10, value: 'Col 10', isChecked: true },
      ],
      isCustomizedOpen: false,
```

Now I am basically calling the Child like this

```
{this.state.isCustomizedOpen &&
          <CustomizedViewInv
            items={filterItems}
          />}
```

Please show me how to move these 3 functions - getCheckBox, handleCheckChildElement and resetFilter from child page to parent page.

I am basically a beginner in React. So please help to me understand what changes I have to move these 3 functions - getCheckBox, handleCheckChildElement and resetFilter from child page to parent page.

Comment: There is another problem with the code: you have duplicated state which can be unpredictable. You need to keep the state in the parent and pass it down in props. Then moving up the functions would be easy. Set up a working https://codesandbox.io with your code and I can edit that for you.

Answer (score 1):

try this approach; let your container have more control over the components
[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/98xm81o3ro)

```
const CheckBox = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={props.item.id}
        type="checkbox"
        checked={props.item.isChecked}
        onClick={props.handleCheckChildElement}
      />
      {props.item.value}
    </div>
  );
};

const Button = props => {
  return <button onClick={() => props.onClick()}>{props.text}</button>;
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    filterItems: [
      { id: 1, value: "Col 1", isChecked: true },
      { id: 2, value: "Col 2", isChecked: true },
      { id: 3, value: "Col 3", isChecked: true },
      { id: 4, value: "Col 4", isChecked: true },
      { id: 5, value: "Col 5", isChecked: true },
      { id: 6, value: "Col 6", isChecked: true },
      { id: 7, value: "Col 7", isChecked: true },
      { id: 8, value: "Col 8", isChecked: true },
      { id: 9, value: "Col 9", isChecked: true },
      { id: 10, value: "Col 10", isChecked: true }
    ]
  };
  handleCheckChildElement(e) {
    alert(e.target.value);
  }
  resetFilter() {
    alert("resetFilter");
  }
  applyFilter() {
    alert("applyFilter");
  }
  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.filterItems.map(item => (
          <CheckBox
            item={item}
            handleCheckChildElement={this.handleCheckChildElement.bind(this)}
          />
        ))}
        <Button text="Reset" onClick={this.resetFilter.bind(this)} />
        <Button text="Apply" onClick={this.applyFilter.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: I have to solve this problem by my technique. Can you help me move those 3 functions from the above mentioned child component to component?

Comment: getCheckBox makes it difficult, not sure you wanna do this way https://codesandbox.io/s/0yzv46l9l0